# Как оптимизировать длинную страницу сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

У меня есть сайт-таблица, где есть поле для подгрузки данных, и в этой таблице после отрисовки более 1000 строк, страница начинает лагать, и требуется заметное время для отрисовки. Как оптимизировать такую таблицу? что бы при подгрузке не лагало, и как поставить гифку загрузки до оканчания выполнения функции js? данных много, и для отрисовки требуется время.

Comment: Можно столбцы скрыть за настройками `show/hidden`. Можно перевернуть таблицу, чтобы было не 1000 столбцов, а 1000 строк. и запилить пагинацию

Comment: @Дмытрык не правильно написал, хотел сказать строк, не хотелось бы пользоваться пагинацией, если есть возможность без использования пагинации, хочу им воспользоваться, если нет так уж и быть перейду на пагинацию, и еще, снизит ли show/hidden нагрузку на отрисовку? если да, то можно было бы задать стиль show/hidden для строк которые не видны пользователю

Comment: подгружайте не сразу все 1000 а по кнопке "показать еще" либо просто когда долистаете до конца

Comment: используется ли какой-либо framework? Типа react, angular и подобного?

Comment: @teran да, тоже думал об этом, но все равно при полной подгрузке всех, более 1000, строк сама страница лагает, т.к много страница длинная и при скролле это заметно

Comment: @Grundy нет, без фреймворка, только js и jquery

Comment: @fredded, для jquery есть множество плагинов, реализующие virtual scroll для таблиц, либо входящие в плагины таблиц, в которых это уже реализовано.